# Ansible - procesor_count vs processor_cores vs processor_vcpus

Tags: multithreading, ansible

I got puzzled setting up server with the following cpu facts:

```
"ansible_processor": [
    "GenuineIntel", 
    "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L v3 @ 1.80GHz", 
    "GenuineIntel", 
    "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L v3 @ 1.80GHz"
], 
"ansible_processor_cores": 1, 
"ansible_processor_count": 2, 
"ansible_processor_threads_per_core": 1, 
"ansible_processor_vcpus": 2,
```

It seems to report the number of CPUs correctly but what should I base my workers (threads) number on? I was sure I'd use `ansible_processor_cores` but it seems to report only one (1 - sic!) despite reporting two processors! How do you get the number of threads available for worker processes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking into the [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.2.3.0-1/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L1136) `ansible_processor_vcpus` should be your choice.
It should contain number of processors in /proc/cpuinfo (which actually is a number of total threads, as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/311788/624525).

Comment: `gather_facts: true` is needed to use `ansible_processor_vcpus` variable

Comment: Thanks, fixed the link.

Comment: Another potential gotcha' I've noticed is that on EC2 instances which have more than one physical CPU the `ansible_processor_cores` variable seems to report the number of cores per CPU, rather than the total number of cores across all CPUs.

Comment: It seems like as of 2020, `ansible_processor_nproc` should be preferred over `_vcpus` (see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/66569)